# Check exact row processed in batch

Tags: apex, batch

Good day everyone,

I have a List of Account with 500 records. I want to insert it using batch by 200. If there is an error during insert, is it possible to trace what exact row does it occur using apex class ? Please help.

Comment: if you have only 500 records then you have  many options available. You can use Database class . In which you will get exact line(Record) in which you are getting error.

Comment: @TusharSharma what about if I have 20000 records is it a different case ?

Comment: Yes it is. then you have to manually check the status and need to store in the some place.